# TestsNodejs - compilers deprecation in mocha and babel

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, tdd, babeljs

I'm building api rest on node with integration test (Babel, chai, mocha)

I changed

```
 --compilers js:babel-core/register
```

for

```
--require babel-core/register
```

as recommended by the documentation: 
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation

But when I make this change in my mocha.opts file, the error appears:

```
C:\Users\Ranulfo\Desktop\noderest>npm run test-integration

> noderest@1.0.0 test-integration C:\Users\Ranulfo\Desktop\noderest
> mocha --opts test/integration/mocha.opts test/integration/*.js

C:\Users\Ranulfo\Desktop\noderest\test\integration\helpers.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import supertest f
rom 'supertest';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

For more details of the code:

mocha.opts(test/integration/mocha):

```
--require test/integration/helpers.js
--reporter spec
--require babel-core/register
--slow 5000
```

helpers.js (test/integration/helpers.js)

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import chai from 'chai';
import app from '../../app';

global.app = app;
global.request = supertest(app);
global.expect = chai.expect;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "noderest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node ./index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "test-integration": "mocha --opts test/integration/mocha.opts test/integration/*.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-node6": "^11.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "supertest": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.10",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Comment: same issue. wondering if you ever resolved?

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the update of "Babel" for version 7, the addition of some configuration steps has occurred.

To adjust the "bug" do the following steps:

Install the specified dependency:
npm install --save-dev @ babel / register
Change the "mocha.opts" file to the compilers for the following line:
--compilers js: @ babel / register
Once this is done, your workflow should be normalized. (I.e.

Note: Look out for the following dependencies that are not present in the tutorial.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli
npm install --save-dev @babel/core
npm install --save-dev @babel/node
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
npm install --save-dev @babel/register
```

**Auxiliary content:**

**Setup:** https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

**Migration:**  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration

**Mocha issues - Compilers deprecation** https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation

Comment: Answer from Ashfaq nisar is spot-on, simple and concise.

Answer (score 3):

For the people who are just here due to the error of deprecation notice of using compilers and have no other issues with the babel.

- Just install the dependency **@babel/register**.
- And change the test script from ***mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register*** to **mocha --require @babel/register**

This should solve your error regarding the error notice from mocha.